# What is "suspension context of a function" in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, coroutine

The "Wording for Coroutines" (document C++ P0057R5) by Gor Nishanov, Jens Maurer, Richard Smith and Daveed Vandevoorde, see [P0057r5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0057r5.pdf), talks a lot about "suspension context of a function" and points directly to "5.3.8"

Where is this defined?

I am asking because, for a process, some times some code is or should have been required to be or not be at certain places. Like Notify (I think it was) that in Java should have been required to be the last statement ("Java’s Insecure Paralleism" by Per Brinch Hansen (1999)). I wonder if suspension context of a function is at such a place?

Comment: No need for that disclaimer. Also we're not _discussing_ here.

Comment: Literally the first hit if you *search* the linked document for the phrase in question...

Comment: No, I didn't think we should discuss, if you are afraid of that.

Comment: I didn't see it defined in that document, just used(?) I asked because I didn't know if this is a C++ generic term or if it in fact is just used in that document. I couldn't find it on stack overflow, so I thought there might be someone who knew. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In exactly the spot in the paper where it says it's defined:

> An *await-expression* shall appear only in a potentially-evaluated expression within the *compound-statement*
>   of a *function-body* outside of a handler (15). In a *declaration-statement* or in the
>   *simple-declaration* (if any) of a *for-init-statement*, an *await-expression* shall appear only in an
>   initializer of that *declaration-statement* or *simple-declaration*. An await-expression shall not
>   appear in a default argument (8.3.6). **A context within a function where an *await-expression* can
>   appear is called a *suspension context* of the function.**

Comment: Blush.. Thanks a lot! (In Norway we say I couldn't see the forest for only trees)